# SQLite converts all unicode characters into ANSI

Tags: sqlite

I have a slight problem with sqlite and its text encoding. I read from documents that sqlite handles UTF-8 encoding or I can use one by executing the command PRAGMA encoding = "UTF-8"; etc.
The database needs to store Polish text. The database is going to be used with Qt later on. I have a script with two commands: CREATE TABLE ... and INSERT INTO ... The file is encoded in UTF-8.
However, when I use command line: sqlite3 myname.db < the_file.sql, I can create both database and the table but all Polish specific characters such as ą, ć, ź, Ż etc. are automatically converted into their simpler ANSI equivalent characters: a, c, z, Z etc. I thought it would be a problem with the command line. So I downloaded SQLite Manager 2009 and when I copy / pasted the whole script to execute it in SQLite Manager, I noticed the effect is the same. Characters are automatically converted during copy / pasting.
Is the SQLite limitted to use only with ANSI characters?

Comment: I would be grateful if someone could link addresses where I could repeat this question. I simply don't understand why things that happen actually happen.

Answer (score 4):

If there is anything wrong in your setup, it is certainly NOT SQLite.

Few simple tests:

Linux:

```
$ cat > test.sql <<EOF
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t;
CREATE TABLE t (str varchar(20));
INSERT INTO  t (str) VALUES ("ą, ć, ź, Ż");
SELECT * FROM t;
EOF

$ file test.sql
test.sql: UTF-8 Unicode text

$ sqlite3 test.db < test.sql
ą, ć, ź, Ż
```

So, it works as doctor prescribed.

Windows:

Use the same `test.sql` as above. If you need to create it anew, copy and paste following text:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t;
CREATE TABLE t (str varchar(20));
INSERT INTO  t (str) VALUES ("ą, ć, ź, Ż");
SELECT * FROM t;
```

into Notepad++ and save as file with Encoding -> **Encode in UTF-8 without BOM**.

```
sqlite3 test.db < test.sql
─Е, ─З, ┼║, ┼╗
```

This sounds bad. But, this is buggy Windows console! Save output to file instead:

```
sqlite3 test.db < test.sql > out.txt
```

Open `out.txt` in Notepad++ - looks great: `ą, ć, ź, Ż`

**EDIT**: It works in Windows console as well, if you use `chcp 65001`:

```
chcp 65001
sqlite3 test.db < test.sql
ą, ć, ź, Ż
```

QED.

Comment: Thanks I have also found the answer. OMG this 2012 and in windows 7 64bit the bloody stupid console still works in OEM 850 codepage. How ridiculous it is, how ridiculous!!!! Thanks for you answer. It just confirmed what I have read about it before :)

Comment: Same thing happens if you output from your program to the console window in Visual Studio. The console seems to not support unicode characters ... all non-ansi ones come out as '?'.

Answer (score -2):

Try replacing your sqlite3.exe file. Sometimes it gets corrupt and becomes able to output only malformed characters (ANSI ones when they should be UTF-8).

Download a fresh copy for the latest version again from:
https://www.sqlite.org/download.html

Comment: If sqlite executable gets corrupted, it will crash, but not mysteriously stop printing UTF-8 - sqlite is always using UTF-8, no matter what (well, it can be UTF-16, but not ANSI).

Comment: It certainly can happen. I should have saved the sample of the corrupted EXE. It fixed itself when I overwrote it with a new sqlite3.exe

Comment: Sorry, but I don't believe you. Even latest sqlite3.exe *will* have this problem - this is not sqlite to blame, but Windows.